# Can template argument deduction for class templates work for non type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Can classes like the following take advantage of [template argument deduction for class templates](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r1.html)?

```
template <int I>
struct Number
{
    /* appropriate constructor here */
};
```

By "take advantage" I mean, is there a way to have (implicitly or explicitly) the value of `I` deduced? An example use would be the following:

```
Number a(3); // a's type is Number<3>
```

Comment: You seem to want the template to create a constructor for you - that's not possible.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Not my intention, just that if knew how to spell the specific constructor I wouldn't be asking the question. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: The `int` template parameter is a compile time thing - it doesn't make sense to pass it to a constructor at run time.

Comment: @NeilButterworth read my comment on Brian's answer

Comment: Yes, but why not simply `Number <3> a;`?

Comment: Perhaps something could be done with a constexpr function. I tried but failed and don't have the time to go further now.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Oh, I see. I'm just trying to do this c++17 style. The same way you'd say `tuple a(2, 1.5)` to generate the type `tuple<int, double>` for `a` using template argument deduction for class [templates](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r1.html). I'm just wondering whether this technique incorporates non-type template parameters

Comment: @Lorah A constructor (or any other function) _does something_  - it's not a type. There is no way of generating what the constructor does from the type of the template.

Comment: @LorahAttkins The key point is that functions (including constructors) must know all the types they are involved with at compile time, but they cannot assume that their arguments are compile time expressions. E.g. if you imagine a factory function (a function that returns `Number<I>`), it must know it's signature at compile time. Since it is a template returning `Number<I>` it must know `I` at compile time. But it cannot know the *value* of its arguments at compile time. Only their type. That's the difference with `make_tuple`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth In C++17 constructors can deduce the type of the class the same way the type of a function template can be deduced from its arguments. Knowing this, what I'm asking is, can we extend this to non-type template parameters? (I mean surely we could wrap them in integral constants but that's just a workaround; is there a more elegant solution?)

Comment: @LorahAttkins To clarify further vis a vis your last comment: this has nothing to do with deducing constructors. What you're asking is impossible; it would require a function to have a way to say: you can only call me with arguments that are `constexpr`. That does not exist in C++.

Comment: @Lorah The point is that in C++ you cannot tell by looking at a function declaration  such as `int f(int n);` what it does. The compiler cannot possibly generate the code to do what it does. The same applies to constructors. What tuple and other constructors do is defined in code. Or maybe I am misunderstanding what you are asking here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth No doubt, no doubt. I'm asking for a user in Stack Overflow to write such a constructor, never said it would be auto generated

Comment: @NeilButterworth I posted a partial solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42544425/4224575). If I were to rephrase the question, it'd read "can we do away with the integral constant in that solution"?

Answer (score 7):

Template argument deduction for class templates can deduce non-type template parameters, but not in the way you're trying to do it.

For example

```
template <std::size_t size>
struct ArrayWrapper {
    ArrayWrapper(std::array<int, size> a);
};
int main() {
    std:array<int, 5> a;
    ArrayWrapper aw(a);  // ok; declares ArrayWrapper<5>
}
```

But in your example you are trying to have a non-type template parameter deduced from the *value* of an argument. In general, the template deduction system of C++ does not support that, whether for class templates or in any other context.

Comment: I assumed this could be done with an `integral_constant` argument (in the constructor) but then I got stuck when it came to converting a numeral to an integral constant. Maybe this is doable with an explicit deduction rule???

Comment: @LorahAttkins I don't think so. Template argument deduction only ever considers the types of arguments, not their values

Answer (score 4):

Template deduction for constructors is still deduction - and deduction is all about types. The only way you can deduce a value is if that value is a non-type template argument of one of the types being deduced. So we can simply lift the `3` from a boring old `int` to a sophisticated, modern `std::integral_constant<int, 3>`:

```
template <int I> using int_t = std::integral_constant<int, I>;
template <int I> constexpr int_t<I> int_c;

template <int I>
struct Number {
    Number(int_t<I> ) { }
};

int main()
{
    Number n(int_c<3> );
}
```

---

Worth noting that the point of this feature is to avoid having to duplicate writing types (such as with `std::lock_guard`), or cases where naming the types may be impossible (such as class template specializations constructed with a lambda). Neither of those really apply here. When you have a value - that's it, just use the value:

```
Number<3> n;
```

That's the same number of characters as `Number n{3}`, which doesn't work, so there's nothing to gain.

Comment: I was writing a similar solution (posted 5' after this one). The way I was looking at it, you can have a conversion constructor with an int parameter while the deduction rule uses an integral constant. It's just a single conversion step away from what I was looking for. I thought some cunning use of the type system (or the ternary operator) could give us that

Answer (score -2):

I'm sharing my (partial) solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <int I>
struct Number
{
    // 1. 
    Number(int) {}
};

// 2. 
template <int K> Number(std::integral_constant<int, K>) -> Number<K>; 

int main()
{
    Number a{std::integral_constant<int, 1>{}}; // look ma, no \<>/
    (void)a; 
    return 0; 
}
```

[**Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SrNPtcwoDYJoy7y2)

What we do on the numbered comments above is:

1. A one argument constructor. This serves as a conversion constructor for when we pass integral constants (comment this out and you get a compilation error)
2. An explicit deduction rule

What all this buys us, is the ability to **declare a `Number` object w/o specifying template arguments** i.e. by merely letting the constructor deduce them. Unfortunately, this solution is elegance-free, since the construction asks for an integral constant (which is then implicitly converted to an integer):

```
Number a{std::integral_constant<int, 1>{}}; // a := Number<int>
```

Taking this a step further would be to devise a way to simply write:

```
Number a{3};
```

but the explicit deduction rule does not work for non-type template parameters, or at least I can't trick it to work.